# facebook app. Iphone app store ID not working

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, sdk

I am setting up a facebook app. It requires iphone app store ID. 
In my itunesConnect I have setup the app and it has given me the AppID, a numeric number. The app is not on the market yet. 
I put that number in my facebook app setup, but it gives me an error, saying we were unable to fetch app from app store. 
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When I give the id for an app that is already on market, it works, but it doesn't let me sign in from the device. It says something went wrong please try again.

Comment: Did you check with any other appstore ID which exist already in app store?

Comment: Yes. With appstore IDs that already exist, setting up passes and the app runs fine in simulator.

Comment: Yes. With other appstore IDs, the setting up passes and the app runs fine on simulator. But when I run it on device, it shows me error. 
'Something went wrong. Please try again later'

Comment: @iosDev82 - From your facebook account leave blank for "iphone app store ID" - Remember you cannot add any existing app id into your facebook account because that app has already registered that ID for thier own FB account

Comment: @bhavyakothari this one did work. could you post it as answer so that I can close it?

Comment: Where do I go to set blank?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your Facebook account leave blank for **iPhone app store ID**

**Remember:** 
You cannot add any existing app id into your Facebook account because that app has already registered that ID for their own FB account

Comment: This was the issue I was facing. Thanks.

Comment: Where do I go to set blank?

Comment: **February 2015** - it is no longer possible to leave these fields blank. It seems filling in `0` still works. See   @Pichirichi answer below.

Comment: If you to try leave blank a lot of times, you can save the form :O

Answer (score 3):

Facebook no longer enable entering a blank AppID.

What you need to do is enter 0 as the App ID and click save.
please note that every change in the app details on Facebook will require entering 0 before save.

Also, you won't be able to login into the app with non developer or testing accounts until the FB app is released.

Comment: Thanks. Note though, that for now we're still able to login with any FB account to our FB app from our unreleased (ad hoc installed) iOS app.

Comment: This no longer works - provide the empty string for your IDs.